# get value from predict_prob in python

Tags: python

```
def py_model(df):
    import pickle
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pandas import Series,DataFrame
    
    filename = 'C:/aaaTENNIS-DATA/votingC.pkl'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))

    filename = 'C:/aaaTENNIS-DATA/votingC.pkl'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
    df['Prediction'] = loaded_model.predict(df[['a','b','c','d']])
    df['Scr']        = loaded_model.predict_proba(df[['a','b','c','d']])[:, 1]
 
    return df
```

Trying to get a value into df[Scr'] but it keeps coming up zer0

Thanks,

Neil.

Comment: There's not enough detail for us to offer meaningful help. It might help to [edit] to include the output of `print(df.head())`, `print(loaded_model)`, and `print(loaded_model.predict_proba(df[['a','b','c','d']]))`

Comment: If I try it in jupyter notebooks using

prediction_is = GBC_model.predict([input])
print('Prediction is ', prediction_is)
print('Accuracy is: ',GBC_model.best_score_)
predictions = GBC_model.predict_proba([input])
print(predictions[0:])
print(predictions[:, 1])
type(predictions)

I get this

Prediction is  [1]
Accuracy is:  0.8888533143602515
[[0.04823177 0.95176823]]
[0.95176823]

Comment: I dont know how to format this to make it easier to read here

Comment: you have to edit the question itself, if formatting is critical

Comment: does `.predict_proba()` returning anything meaningful? how do you know? you can use PDB to debug programs https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html or simply give it a name and see what the result is intermediate with `print()`

Comment: in jupyter notebooks it returns  [[0.04823177 0.95176823]] . This would be fine as I just want the accuracy associated with a prediction of 1 which is the 0.95176823

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.